# autofocus in ngx-otp-input doesn't work in ionic 5

Tags: input, ionic5, autofocus

I tried ngx-otp-input with ionic 5 like in the example https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-otp-input#otpchange , but **autofocus** doesn't work for me.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Add in HTML`

```
<ngx-otp-input [config]="otpInputConfig" (otpChange)="handeOtpChange($event)" (fill)="handleFillEvent($event)">
    </ngx-otp-input>
```

`Add in TS File`

```
otpInputConfig: NgxOtpInputConfig = {
    otpLength: 6,
    autofocus: true,
    classList: {
      inputBox: "my-super-box-class",
      input: "my-super-class",
      inputFilled: "my-super-filled-class",
      inputDisabled: "my-super-disable-class",
      inputSuccess: "my-super-success-class",
      inputError: "my-super-error-class"
    }
  };

  handeOtpChange(value: string[]): void {
    console.log(value);
  }

  handleFillEvent(value: string): void {
    console.log(value);
  }
```